# Configurar Tortoise SVN com Google Drive

Tags: github, svn, tortoisegit

Preciso de uma ajuda, estou querendo configurar o Tortoise SVN para subir meus projetos no Google Drive alguém já fez essa configuração? Se sim teria como me auxiliar com isso, estou tendo dificuldades.

Eu tentei configurar o Github, mas achei um pouco lento o processo de sincronização (upload), talvez eu fiz a configuração incorretamente, se alguém tiver algum link contendo um vídeo ou um manual seria interessante, ou ainda, se tiver outras alternativas me informem...

Agradeço...

Dieggo

Comment: Qual o tamanho do seu repositório?